# Running jQuery against tinymce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I'm working in chrome console and trying to add some jQuery there in order to manipulate runtime styles of objects inside the WordPress TinyMCE editor.

I have a div element inside the editor with class "my_box" and I'm trying to manipulate the runtime style via jQuery like so:

```
jQuery('#tinymce .my_box').hover(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('style','border:3px dashed red')
    }
);
```

However, when I run this in console, the DOM result set is empty []. How can I attach events to objects inside the tinymce editor and where should I place my script once I've tested it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this runs it will find whatever instances of `.my_box` exist at that time within the wrapper. If they aren't there at that time, or `#tinymce` is not a true wrapper but something tinymce is generating, then the selector below will find nothing.

```
jQuery('#tinymce .my_box').hover(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('style','border:3px dashed red')
    }
);
```

Consider instead something like this, where `#tinymceWrap` is an independent div wrapping the editor:

```
jQuery('#tinymceWrap').hover(
    function(){
        // use find here so jquery will search for `.my_box` instances again on each hover
        jQuery(this).find('.my_box').css('border','3px dashed red');
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. At least now I get a result set. Although it does not appear to be applying the runtime styles to the elements its matching.